# Return the color of the most recently added Spot in the spots array

Tags: javascript

I am creating spots on the canvas that change colors randomly. How do i access the last spot in the array and return the color? the color of the L should change to the color of the most recent spot added in order to know I am doing it right.

```
function lastColor() {
  var lastColor = color(255);
  var result = spots.map(a => a.color); {
}
  return lastColor;
}

function drawLastColor() {
  fill(lastColor());
  textSize(50);
  text("L", 10, 50);
}
```

Comment: This is just "how do I get the lest element in an array", and SO has quite a few answers for this question already. Remember to [search and research](/help/how-to-ask) before posting, because quite often someone already had the same question you did, and it'll have an answer on SO already. Google is also a good source here, just searching for "javascript last element in array" gets you tons of great results.

Answer (score 0):

```
var colorArray = [...lots of colors]

var lastColor = colorArray[colorArray.length - 1]
```